# Unable to programmatically "push" viewcontroller using showSegue in IOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, segue

I have defined a segue from source tableview controller to another and trying to programmatically transition to the destination controller upon click of a `UITableViewCell` using the following statement:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToDestinationViewController" sender:self];
```

However, I find that the segue doesn't result in a "push" to the destination view controller.

On the other hand, if I wire the segue to a specific cell in the source view controller it works.

In addition, if I call the destination viewcontroller programmatically using:

```
[self showViewController:DestinationViewController] it works.
```

Can someone advise if this is a known issue in iOS 8 or if I am missing something here.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the method where you call  performSegueWithIdentifier: is actually executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a segue in your Storyboard called `pushToDestinationViewController`? You will need to make sure that you have this segue in your Storyboard first like below.

[image]

Or, if you just want to simply push another view controller, you can just use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController]`.

Comment: I am using adaptive view controller in IOS8 with show segue given push is deprecated. I do have the segue named in the storyboard. The issue is with defining the segue at the tableviewcontroller level instead of from a tableview cell.

Comment: @everestman Ok, did you make sure that you select `Show (e.g. Push)` on the Storyboard segue? I've also done this with a table view controller and it works fine.

Comment: I figured out the issue - I had defined a - performseguewithidentifier method in my class that did an override of the default behavior to push the view controller. Taking out the method now fixed the issue